# Calculate p test for the data given below

Tags: statistics

[image]

I am given these datas and I have to calculate the p value using p test ,I've been watching youtube videos for more than an hour and yet I couldn't find anything that would explain simply how to do it.If anyone could help me with this one,I would really appreciate it. Thank you !

Comment: Please explain a little more what the data is and what it is you want to test, example: the difference in means between the two groups? Also, you have a +/- value against what I assume is a mean. It really needs to be a standard deviation rather than the range of the values. Given this data, and that other criteria are met for a valid test, a t - test for the difference in means would be appropriate.

Comment: The data is the activity of transaminaza enzymes(AST and ALT) in albuminore glands on snail Helix pomatia I.That's all I'm given I don't know what to do now.It's a biology project but it needs statistics calculations.

Comment: And the 17.5 +/- 7.5 is a mean and range of the data? Like I said, it needs to be a standard deviation. Do you have data on all 20 values?

Comment: yes I have data on all 20 values but I don't know what to do with them?

Comment: These values are arithmetic mean of those 20 values

Comment: And the +/- 7.5?

Comment: I used standard deviation and arithmetic mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78481/discussion-between-phil-h-and-maths-survivor).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm assuming that all criteria for a valid test is met, random samples etc.

Also, for the equation, $\bar x$ is the sample mean, $s$ is the sample standard deviation and $n$ is the sample size.